# Multinomial logit with time-varying alternative-specific constants

Tags: r, regression, discrete-data, multinomial-logit, mlogit

I observe some individuals (labeled `id`) that have made a choice from a set (the alternative variable is `alt`). The choice set remains constant, but choices are made at different periods (`year`). Also, all individuals from the sample are unique (i.e. I do not observe individuals making choices at different periods). Here's what the dataset looks like (**edited with a reproducible example**):

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,10,10,10), 
                  alt=c("A", "B", "C","A", "B", "C","A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
                  year=c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002),
                  choice=c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0, 0,1,0, 0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0),
                  alt_year=c("A_2000", "B_2000", "C_2000", "A_2001", "B_2001", "C_2001", "A_2000", "B_2000", "C_2000", "A_2002", "B_2002", "C_2002", "A_2001", "B_2001", "C_2001", "A_2002", "B_2002", "C_2002", "A_2000", "B_2000", "C_2000", "A_2001", "B_2001", "C_2001", "A_2002", "B_2002", "C_2002", "A_2002", "B_2002", "C_2002"),
                  x=c(4.084898, 4.895566, 3.770222, 4.836619, 2.254944, 5.689459, 4.864778, 3.849224, 2.550993, 4.643009, 4.483194, 3.993644, 4.151456, 3.415891, 4.368807, 4.294654, 3.720741, 2.663763, 4.700749, 4.554197, 3.163693, 2.405412, 4.204959, 3.654912, 4.252612, 2.705998, 3.040830, 5.085775, 4.403775, 4.586488))

head(df1,12)

   id alt year choice alt_year        x
1   1   A 2000      0   A_2000 4.084898
2   1   B 2000      0   B_2000 4.895566
3   1   C 2000      1   C_2000 3.770222
4   2   A 2001      1   A_2001 4.836619
5   2   B 2001      0   B_2001 2.254944
6   2   C 2001      0   C_2001 5.689459
7   3   A 2000      1   A_2000 4.864778
8   3   B 2000      0   B_2000 3.849224
9   3   C 2000      0   C_2000 2.550993
10  4   A 2002      0   A_2002 4.643009
11  4   B 2002      1   B_2002 4.483194
12  4   C 2002      0   C_2002 3.993644
```

I would like to fit a multinomial/conditional logit (McFadden's Random Utility Model, to be more precise) in which the parameter associated with the `x` explanatory variable would be constant, but alternative-specific constants would be able to vary over time. Forcing the parameter associated with `x` to be constant requires estimating the model for the whole dataset instead of estimating the model separately for each year. My objective is to analyze the evolution in the alternative-specific constants over time, e.g. relative to "A_2000".

Do you know if this is possible and, if so, how it could be reached? I'm currently using the `mlogit` package in `R`.

Thanks for helping,
Val

**EDIT:**

I tried to include the year variable as an individual-specific variable, this way:

```r
dfx1 <- mlogit.data(df1, index=c("id", "alt"), choice="choice", shape="long", alt.levels = c("A", "B", "C"))
model <- mlogit(choice ~ x | as.factor(year)+ 0, reflevel="C", data=dfx1)
```

When doing so, the model provides estimates for alternatives "A" and "B" and for years 2001 and 2002. Note tha the predicted market shares perfectly match the observed ones, in the same way as when including alternative-specific constants.

```
Coefficients :
                       Estimate Std. Error z-value Pr(>|z|)
x                      0.372386   0.543756  0.6848   0.4934
as.factor(year)2001:A  0.274216   1.466484  0.1870   0.8517
as.factor(year)2001:B  0.405499   1.537000  0.2638   0.7919
as.factor(year)2002:A  0.326106   1.336744  0.2440   0.8073
as.factor(year)2002:B -0.097479   1.425090 -0.0684   0.9455
```

I know that alternative-specific constants have to be interpreted relative to the reference alternative, which intercept value is set to 0. Here, the coefficient for "2001:A" would thus have to be interpreted relative to "2001:C". But I guess it should also be interpreted relative to the reference level of the year variable, i.e. "2000". For instance, and without paying attention to significance here, is it correct to say that in 2002,  compared to 2000, the unobservables have had a negative impact on the probability for developers to choose alternative B relative to alternative C? Ultimately, I would like to know if it makes sense to display such a timeline:

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Based on the above figure, I would say that the relative effect of unobservables on the probability of choosing alternative A has increased with time. However, nothing could be said about the absolute level of this effect. For instance, if the value of alternative A specific constant in year 2000 is negative, I would like to be able to say if this increase has lead the value of this constant to be positive, i.e. to exceed alternative C specific constant.

I wonder if it would be correct to estimate the model on the subset of `df1` in which `year == 2000` to have the original value for $\alpha_A^{2000}$ and $\alpha_B^{2000}$, and then to consider, from the above regression, that $\alpha_A^{2001} = \alpha_A^{2000} + 0.274216$. What would remain is the fact that the estimate associated with the `x` variable would be different between the two models.

Comment: I am not sure what your design matrix is from the `R` formulae. I am looking at reproducing it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74090526/how-to-reproduce-https-stats-stackexchange-com-q-592459-69508-in-statsmodels).

Comment: Hi, I'm very sorry about the misunderstanding but the dataset displayed here is not complete at all and was just meant to illustrate the issue!

Comment: Just edited with a reproducible example. Sorry again!